# How can I link to next or previous record belonging to an object in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have have an image(tattoo) sharing site with 3 different ways of indexing images. The main page that just shows Image.all, member's images which shows @member.images.all, and member's album images. That is to say, the a Member has many images (and albums), and an Album has many images.

Now when you click on an image, regardless of where it was (index, member's profile, or member's album) you get to the show page. Im thinking I probably need a previous and next link to show the next image but I need to be able to restrict the images to their parent container.

So if Im looking at an image within an album, I would need the next and previous links to only link to images in that album. If Im looking at a member's images NOT in an album it the links would point to images the member owns, not in an album.

And if the image was in the front page, then the links would just point to ALL images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want pagination, then you'd have to do additional queries to ensure the links to the next/previous records are accurate. Example shown below...

In your image model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album

  def previous
    Image.where("album_id = ? AND id < ?", self.album.id, self.id).first
  end
  def next
    Image.where("album_id = ? AND id > ?", self.album.id, self.id).first
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
def show
  @current_image = Image.find(params[:id])
  @prev = @current_image.previous
  @next = @current_image.next

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

And finally in your view (this is HAML code):

```
= link_to_unless(@prev.blank?, 'Prev', image_path(@prev))
= link_to_unless(@next.blank?, 'Next', image_path(@next))
```

Just keep in mind that `previous` and `next` could return `nil` if no previous or next image is found so you should not show the prev / next links in that scenario.

---

If you end up using the `will_paginate` or `Kaminari` gem (highly recommended), you can generate "pretty" routes by just adding a matched route to your routes.rb file:

```
match '/albums/:id/page/:page' => "albums#show"

# put the matched route above the regular :albums resource
# so it matches that route first if it's given a page
resources :albums
```

The reason that works is because both pagination gems use Rails `url_for` method to generate the previous/next links and therefore Rails will match that route and generate something like http://rtattoos.com/albums/2/page/26 instead of http://rtattoos.com/albums/2?page=26

Comment: This is pretty awesome, but it doesnt seem to restrict the next/previous image to whats in the parent container.

then again I got an error because of the respond_with line:
`RuntimeError (In order to use respond_with, first you need to declare the formats your controller responds to in the class level)`

Comment: It's just a generic example :)  I don't know your model or controller setup, so I just wanted to show you one way of doing it.  You will have to slightly modify the code to fit your current setup.  Like `Image.where("album_id = ? AND id < ?", self.album.id, self.id).first` etc. You don't need to use `respond_with`, you can use the normal `respond_to` format block instead.  Again, this was just an example

Comment: @rugbert By the way, I updated my answer and added an example showing how to easily generate "pretty" routes using the will_paginate gem.

Comment: awesome, Ill try that out when I get home and think about giving will_paginate another shot. Right now Im using Kaminari for paginating the index since It's easier to style, the routing line should accomplish the same thing right?

Comment: @rugbert I'm pretty sure Kaminari uses `url_for` as well for route generation, so it *should* work the same way I described above (as long as you have the matched route).  So I wouldn't necessarily switch to `will_paginate`, just try Kaminari first and see if it works

Comment: Ahh ok, well your solutions worked. However, I realize that there is a major logistics issue I need to work out before it's user functional. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical pagination type problem.  Each display of records always comes with some kind of conditions (even if it is `find(:all)`).  Take a look at [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) for easy creation of the view and collection objects.  The only additional work is always providing the conditions back on a page change to reissue model request with the next set.

Comment: I dont think I want to paginate it because Im trying to have clean URLs for linking and sharing.

Comment: I posted an example showing how to do it without pagination, but I'm agreeing with Nick on this one that pagination would be best.  I don't think I really understand how this would make your URLs dirty since you can format that however you wish

Comment: I mean, when Ive used will_paginate in the past, clicking next would add something like ?page=2 to the URL whereas I want my urls to be the direct link to the image view

Comment: How would you envision the URL looking for page 2 of a particular view of a listing of images (e.g. page 2 of a particular user's images)?  I'd assume that each image specific link wouldn't be paginated: `/imgs/12345`.

Comment: like:
`http://rtattoos.com/tattoo/220` or
`members/loose-screw-tattoo/tattoos/26` or `/members/loose-screw-tattoo/albums/2/tattoo/26`

Comment: Would each of those examples point to a listing of images or just one image?

Answer (score 0):

If in the show page you have `@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])` You could try passing the id of the current photo to either a nextPhoto or a previousPhoto method. The nextPhoto method would then have `@photo = Photo.find(id + 1)` and previousPhoto have `@photo = Photo.find(id -1)`. I'm not sure if this syntax works but something along these lines seems to be what you are looking for.